# Regex to Parse Mail Subject with multiple encoding

Tags: regex, parsing, email

There!

I want to match all the Inline Encodings in one Mail-Subject and build the Subject String in utf8.

Some Examples:

```
[Listname | Topic123] =?utf-8?Q?encodedtext?=
=?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?=
Klartext-Betreff
[Listname | Topic123] =?utf-8?Q?encodedtext?= =?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?=
=?ISO-8859-1?B?SWYgeW91IGNhbiByZWFkIHRoaXMgeW8=?=
    =?ISO-8859-2?B?dSB1bmRlcnN0YW5kIHRoZSBleGFtcGxlLg==?=
```

I also got a mail with two different encodings (example in Last line).

In E-Mails it could also be possible, that the subject is split in multiple lines where each line (except the first) starts with at least one whitespace

So I am looking for a regex, that parses:

Part+

Where Part is one of:

- Text with spaces
- =?charset?encoding?encoded-text?=

I think it woll go to something like:

```
ENC = (=\?)([A-Za-z0-9-]*)(\?)([A-Za-z0-9-]*)(?)([Any Character])(\?=)
Part = any character that doesnt match to ENC or ENC
```

Comment: What language or tool and what have you tried?

Comment: Language: PHP, I would use preg_match_all.  I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know how to form that regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function decode ($string, $source_enc, $dest_enc)
{
    $parts = preg_split (
        '/=\?([^?]+)\?([^?]+)\?([^?]+)\?=/', 
        $string, 
        -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    $result = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($parts); $i++)
    {
        $part = $parts [$i];

        if ($i % 4 == 0)
            $result .= iconv ($source_enc, $dest_enc, $part);
        else
        {
            $charset = $parts [$i++];
            $encoding = $parts [$i++];
            $text = $parts [$i];

            if ($encoding == 'Q' || $encoding == 'q')
                $text = quoted_printable_decode ($text);
            else if ($encoding == 'B' || $encoding == 'b')
                $text = base64_decode ($text);

            $result .= iconv ($charset, $dest_enc, $text);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

echo (decode ("=?utf-8?Q?encodedtext?= =?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?=
=?ISO-8859-1?B?SWYgeW91IGNhbiByZWFkIHRoaXMgeW8=?=
    =?ISO-8859-2?B?dSB1bmRlcnN0YW5kIHRoZSBleGFtcGxlLg==?=", 
    "ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Output for me is:

```
encodedtext this is some text If you can read this yo u understand the example.
```

Comment: Where do I get the sorce encoding from - Is that the "Content-Type: ... charset="" encoding? Does that handle clear text also? eg. I have a clear [List] as first part, that isn't encoded like the other parts?

Comment: @user1997286 According to this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word everything outside =?...?= should use only ASCII characters, so source encoding could probably be 'ISO-8859-1' all the time.

Comment: If there's set a Transfer-Encoding: ... charset="x" Header; would then be X the charset of the Subject or still ISO-8859-1? Other Question: If I use that part in my code, do you mind linking your stackoverflow account with a thank?